# Remover duplicidade de lista com Python

Tags: python

Preciso remover da lista os objetos que possuem mesma `conta`, `saldo_devedor`, e que o `limite` seja igual a `0`.

```
list = [
          {
            'conta': u'1.3.02', 
            'saldo_devedor': 999.08, 
            'limite': 2500.0
          }, 
          { 'conta': u'1.3.02', 
            'saldo_devedor': 999.08, 
            'limite': 0.0
          },
          { 'conta': u'1.3.03', 
            'saldo_devedor': 600.00, 
            'limite': 1000.00
          }
        ]
```

No caso existem 2 registros que possuem mesma `conta` e `saldo_devedor`, mas a que tem o `limite` igual a `0` tem que ser removida, deixando assim a lista:

```
list = [
          {
            'conta': u'1.3.02', 
            'saldo_devedor': 999.08, 
            'limite': 2500.0
          },
          { 'conta': u'1.3.03', 
            'saldo_devedor': 600.00, 
            'limite': 1000.00
          }
        ]
```

Tentei um exemplo que vi, mas da erro e não sei se é assim o jeito que pode feito isso:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x, y: x.conta == y.conta and x.saldo_devedor == y.saldo_devedor and x.limit != 0, list_1))
```

Erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 18, in <module>
    new_list = list(filter(lambda x, y: x.conta == y.conta and x.saldo_devedor == y.saldo_devedor and x.limit != 0, list_1))
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'y'
```

Comment: Qual o problema apresentado com o seu código?

Comment: Sou novo com Python, então não sei como fazer, `new_list = filter(lambda x, y: x.conta == y.conta and x.saldo_devedor == y.saldo_devedor and x.limit ==  0, list_1)`, tentei isso ai, mas não funcionou.

Comment: Saberia fazer utilizando `for` (ao invés de utilizar filter e lambda)?

Comment: Utilizai um `for` mesmo para resolver, mas gostaria de saber se tem uma solução melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução:

```
[x for x in consulta_limite if not ([y['conta'] for y in consulta_limite].count(x['conta']) > 1 and not [z['saldo_devedor'] for z in consulta_limite].count(x['saldo_devedor']) == 0 and x['limite'] == 0.0)]
```

Esse cara me retorna ja a lista filtrada

Answer (score 0):

Fiz uma função mas simples de entender. Ela recebe por parâmetro sua lista e os índices que você quer comparar, que nesse caso é o primeiro e o segundo. A função deleta os dados duplicados confirme você definiu.

```
# Recebe lista, indice1, indice 2
def remove_duplicada(lista, x, y):
    if lista[x]["conta"] == lista[y]["conta"] and lista[x]["saldo_devedor"] == lista[y]["saldo_devedor"]:
        if lista[x]["limite"] == 0.0:
            del lista[x]
        else:
            del lista[y]

remove_duplicada(lista, 1, 0)
print(lista)
```